# simple issue with data flow (springboot, reactJS, axios)

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, axios, spring-restcontroller

Spring + React

1. Controller:

   ```
   @Component
   @RestController
   public class UsersController {

       @Autowired
       UsersSource usersSource;

       @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
       public boolean testUser(@RequestBody User user){
           String email = user.getEmail();
           String password = user.getPassword();
           Optional<User> optUser = usersSource.checkIfExist(email);
           if(optUser.isPresent()){
               if(optUser.get().getPassword().equals(password)) {
                   System.out.println("return true"); //WORKING
                   return true;
               }
           }
           System.out.println("return false"); //WORKING
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```
2. part of view:

...

```
    axios.post('http://localhost:8088/', data)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);    //NOT WORKING
        });
```

...

**Problem:** data ir correctly delivered to RestController and **"System.out.println("return true");"** 
or 
**"System.out.println("return false");"**
works fine, 
but i dont see:
**console.log(response)**

It is so easy, but i cant handle this problem, please help.

Comment: Do you see the response preview in browser dev tools ?

Comment: i know that this should be visible in browser dev tools not in regular console :)

Comment: but it is already done. Thx for interests. I had sth wrong with my browser, when i reset settings to default it works (i'm not sure why)

Answer (score 0):

It was not problem with CODE. Thx for interests. I had sth wrong with my browser, when i reset settings to default it works (i'm not sure why), and it is visible in browser web tool now.